# Applying color to Strings in Paragraph using Itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am combining 2 strings to Paragraph this way,

```
String str2="";
String str1="";
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.setSimpleColumn(36, 600, 600, 800);
ct.addElement(new Paragraph(str1 + str2));
int status1 = ct.go();
```

The problem is I am getting same font color for both str1 & str2.

I want to have different font color and size for str1 & str2..

How Can i do that on ColumnText/Paragraph?

Can someone help me in this...

Comment: I have updated your question because you were creating a PDF with **illegal syntax**. It is **forbidden** to nest `BT`/`ET` sequences! Please stick to what is explained in the documentation!!!

Comment: I've added your question to my book: https://leanpub.com/itext_so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you combine text into a `Paragraph` like this:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("abc" + "def");
```

You implicitly tell iText that `"abc"` and `"def"` should be rendered using the same (default) font. As you probably know, a `Paragraph` is a collection of `Chunk` objects. In iText, a `Chunk` is like an atomic part of text in the sense that all the text in a `Chunk` has the same font, font size, font color, etc...

If you want to create a `Paragraph` with different font colors, you need to compose your `Paragraph` using different `Chunk` objects. This is shown in the [ColoredText](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/ColoredText) example:

```
Font red = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
Chunk redText = new Chunk("This text is red. ", red);
Font blue = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLUE);
Chunk blueText = new Chunk("This text is blue and bold. ", blue);
Font green = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.ITALIC, BaseColor.GREEN);
Chunk greenText = new Chunk("This text is green and italic. ", green);
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(redText);
document.add(p1);
Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph();
p2.add(blueText);
p2.add(greenText);
document.add(p2);
```

In this example, we create two paragraphs. One with a single `Chunk` in red. Another one that contains two `Chunk`s with a different color.

In your question, you refer to `ColumnText`. The next code snippet uses `p1` and `p2` in a `ColumnText` context:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(36, 600, 144, 760));
ct.addElement(p1);
ct.addElement(p2);
ct.go();
```

As a result, the paragraphs are added twice: once positioned by iText, once positioned by ourselves by defining coordinates using a `Rectangle`:

[image: Screen shot]