# How can I use regular and bold in a single String?

Tags: itext, itextpdf

I have a `String` that consists of a constant part and a variable part.
I want the variable to be formatted using a regular font within the text paragraph, whereas I want the constant part to be bold.

This is my code:

```
String cc_cust_name = request.getParameter("CC_CUST_NAME");    
document.add(new Paragraph(" NAME  " + cc_cust_name, fontsmallbold));
```

My code for a cell in a table looks like this:

```
cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date of Birth" + cc_cust_dob ,fontsmallbold));
```

In both cases, the first part (`" NAME "` and `"Date of Birth"`) should be bold and the variable part (`cc_cust_name` and `cc_cust_dob`) should be regular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now you are creating a `Paragraph` using a single font: `fontsmallbold`. You want to create a `Paragraph` that uses two different fonts:

```
Font regular = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12);
Font bold = Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("NAME: ", bold);
p.add(new Chunk(CC_CUST_NAME, regular));
```

As you can see, we create a `Paragraph` with content `"NAME: "` that uses font `bold`. Then we add a `Chunk` to the `Paragraph` with `CC_CUST_NAME` in font `regular`.

See also [How to set two different colors for a single string in itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256581/how-to-set-two-different-colors-for-a-single-string-in-itext) and [Applying color to Strings in Paragraph using Itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578497/applying-color-to-strings-in-paragraph-using-itext) which are two questions that address the same topic.

You can also use this in the context of a `PdfPCell` in which case you create a `Phrase` that uses two fonts:

```
Font regular = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12);
Font bold = Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD);
Phrase p = new Phrase("NAME: ", bold);
p.add(new Chunk(CC_CUST_NAME, regular));
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(p);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this one little more thing i want for this as well                `PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(2);  PdfPCell cell4;   cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Married"+CC_STATUS,fontsmallbold));    in this i want CC_STATUS in regular font and Married in bold font which i getting already

Comment: You should create the `Phrase` in the exact same way I created the `Paragraph` in my answer. I'll update my answer to show what I mean.